# How to get a value from a Json array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a function in php that returns this json array, this is the function

```
    $token = $db->getTokenFromEmail($email);
    echo $token;
```

and this is what i get:

```
[{"unique_id":"cBuJ-xsDDAo:APA91bHYgPwuwXGVxNMuW_Xs0u5bvbr_QSJq8G1_tZ-nGHOdRB0Nv5ijb2BcaP_wUkpyxwERo7cuQxj89YHjOZdIeIwBOGyeHMP_Ywkg_mocfZQr-CxOzy41i8GKj3X6WFjLZJU4ZcbK"}]
```

My question is how can I get the value (cBuJ-xsD...)?
I have tried this but it doesn't work

```
$obj = json_decode($token,true);
    echo $obj['unique_id'];
```

Comment: its another dimension inside, `print_r` it, and you'll see the structure

Comment: What do you mean? Can you explain me ? (I'm sorry, I'm a newbie in this subject ) @Ghost

Comment: the answer's below, check it out

Comment: @Ghost a vote will be appreciated :) thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your token's type is a string, and you are correct to use `json_decode`.

If you try to `var_dump` the value you will get:

```
$token = '[{"unique_id":"cBuJ-xsDDAo:APA91bHYgPwuwXGVxNMuW_Xs0u5bvbr_QSJq8G1_tZ-nGHOdRB0Nv5ijb2BcaP_wUkpyxwERo7cuQxj89YHjOZdIeIwBOGyeHMP_Ywkg_mocfZQr-CxOzy41i8GKj3X6WFjLZJU4ZcbK"}]';
$obj = json_decode($token,true);
var_dump($obj);
```

And the output is:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["unique_id"]=>
    string(152) "cBuJ-xsDDAo:APA91bHYgPwuwXGVxNMuW_Xs0u5bvbr_QSJq8G1_tZ-nGHOdRB0Nv5ijb2BcaP_wUkpyxwERo7cuQxj89YHjOZdIeIwBOGyeHMP_Ywkg_mocfZQr-CxOzy41i8GKj3X6WFjLZJU4ZcbK"
  }
}
```

You can see that the `$obj` variable is an array, and it's first element is another array that has the `unique_id` key.

To get to that you should use:

```
$obj[0]['unique_id'];
```

Comment: I'm so grateful! Just what I needed. Thank you!